# WPF MVVM, Increment and Decrement Datagrid Cell Value on Button Click

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

[image]

how do i increment cell value when i click plus button and decrement on minus button

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public decimal Product_Quantity { get; set; }
    ...
```

Observeable Collection in viewmodel

```
private ObservableCollection<ProductModel> mProducts;
public ObservableCollection<ProductModel> Products
{
    get { return mProducts; }
    set { mProducts= value; }
}
```

SelectedRow

```
 private ProductModel mSelectedRow;
 public ProductModel SelectedRow
 {
    get => mSelectedRow;
    set
    {
        mSelectedRow = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRow");
    }
 }
```

Datagrid binding

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}"
```

and here is my DataGridTextColumn where i want to show updated value

```
<DataGridTextColumn
    Width="auto"
    MinWidth="50"
    Binding="{Binding Product_Quantity}"
    ElementStyle="{StaticResource BlockDataGridTextColumn}"
    Header="Quantity"/>
```

and finaly

```
private ICommand mIncrementCommand;
    public ICommand IncrementCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mIncrementCommand == null)
            {
                mIncrementCommand = new DelegateCommand(delegate ()
                {
                    // logic goes here
                });
            }
            return mIncrementCommand;
        }
    }
```

Updated, i want somthing like below

```
private ICommand mIncrementCommand;
    public ICommand IncrementCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mIncrementCommand == null)
            {
                mIncrementCommand = new DelegateCommand(delegate ()
                {
                    SelectedRow.Product_Quantity++;
                });
            }
            return mIncrementCommand;
        }
    }
```

Solved, Thanks Rahul Agarwal

```
public class ProductModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public decimal Product_Quantity { get; set; }
    ...
```

I forgot to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind '+' and '-' button with `ICommand` base properties in `ProductModel` class. Say like :

```
public ICommand IncrementCommand{ /* provide ICommand execute implementation*/}
public ICommand DecrementCommand{ /* provide ICommand execute implementation*/}
```

Your `execute` method of ICommand implementation should take care of adding/removing from `Product_Quantity`. For that to reflect back in result grid,  `Product_Quantity` also need to notify - hence your `ProductModel` should also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Though its not obvious from your code, you need to have these `ICommand` implementation in `ProductModel` class and not main view model because data context for `itemtemplate` (each row) of `itemcontrol` is `ProductModel`

Comment: thanks @Rahul, my question is how do i Increment and decrement quantity, e.g if quantity is 1 then on increment it should become 2, '+' is for Increment and '-' is decrement

Comment: @UsmanAli : you need to bind `+` and `-` button command property with `IncrementCommand` and `DecrementCommand` implementation in `ProductModel`. `mIncrementCommand = new DelegateCommand(delegate ()
                {
                    Product_Quantity++;
                });`

Comment: thanks again @Rahul, i have already tried this but its not working, value is not updating on cell,

Comment: Did your productmodel implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` ? I don't see that in code snippet your provided though.